# Angular 4/5/6 - document status as 404 on page refresh

Tags: angular, .htaccess, nginx

Just for clarification, this question is not related to "Error 404" page not found issue while missing the .htaccess redirection.

Its an Angular 5 app hosted on Nginx where normal angular routing works well, on page refresh the page loads as expected.

But if you check the `Chrome developer tool -> Network tab -> filtered with "Doc"`, can see the 404 status for that route.

Scenario:

1. http://example.com redirects to http://example.com/home route via angular.
2. On refresh, it shows the below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thats because there is no `home` page and instead fo getting error you are redirected to `http://example.com` Try with `http://example.com/testing` and you will get the same result.

You need to setup your angular routes and set default route in a case when there is no requested URL.

[Angular route](https://angular.io/guide/router)